# X86 assembly: got segmentation fault after executing "ret" in the main function, why?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86

```
.data
  format: .asciz "%lx, %lx, %lx, %lx\n"
.text
.global main
.extern printf
main:
    movq $6, %rax  # op1
    movq $7, %rbx  # op2
    movq $8, %r8   # id
    movq $9, %r9   # signed
    
    cmpq %rax, %rbx
    jne _fakertn
_fakertn2:
    pushq %rax
    pushq %rbx
    pushq %r8
    pushq %r9
    call _myfunc
    xorq %rax, %rax
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret

_fakertn:
    jmp _fakertn2
    
_myfunc:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    leaq format(%rip), %rdi
    movq 16(%rbp), %r8
    movq 24(%rbp), %rcx
    movq 32(%rbp), %rdx
    movq 40(%rbp), %rsi
    xorq %rax, %rax
    call printf          
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    movq $0, %rax
    ret
```

I compiled with the following command: gcc test.s -g -no-pie -o test

Here is the standard output:

6, 7, 8, 9

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

The segmentation fault happened after executing ret in the main function.

I spent 5 hours on this and still can't find out the cause. Please help to identify the problem. Thanks!

Comment: For a small program like this, the best way to debug it is to step through it one instruction at a time, and after each instruction, inspect the registers and memory to confirm that they match what you expect them to contain. At some point, your expectation will diverge from reality. That's where the bug is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your preamble in `_myfunc`:

```
_myfunc:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
```

And the postamble, which "undoes" the preamble:

```
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    movq $0, %rax
    ret
```

Now check the postamble to `_main`:

```
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

Where's `_main`'s preamble?

You're popping off the return address into `rbp` - assuming that `rbp` contained what you wanted in the previous instruction!

[Edit]

@RaymondChen makes a point about the fact that you are pushing the parameters onto the stack, but not explicitly cleaning them up. This is bad practice - but (luckily?) you're not affected by this because the stack is "fixed up" immediately after the call anyway.

When you push parameters onto the stack, something has to take them off again. There are only two ways this can be done: by the function itself as it returns, or by the caller after it is returned to.

For example, if you push four integers onto the stack, then call a function, the function *could* do a `ret $4*8` to pop those four eight-byte registers. Your `_myfunc` function could do this.

The other alternative is used when the called function doesn't know how many parameters have been pushed, like `printf()` doesn't. Your example uses registers rather than the stack for the arguments to `printf()`, but there are times when the stack is used - especially if there are a lot of parameters! If four parameters for `printf()` are `push`ed onto the stack, `printf` can't do a `ret $4*8` because it doesn't know how many there were. So instead, the caller (your `_myfunc`) should add `$4 * 8` to `rsp` straight after the return.

Like I said, the next instruction is "move `rbp` to `rsp`" anyway, so the add is (strictly) unnecessary - but good practice nevertheless!

Comment: There are also four unmatched push instructions at `_fakertn2`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Hello Raymond, Thanks for identifying the problems. I am new to assembly. could you please be more specific about the unmatched push inst?

Comment: @syacer Everything you push on the stack must be popped off the stack before you return.  You don't do this, so returning from the function fails.  Recall that a return instruction just pops a return address of the stack.  If there is other junk on the stack, `ret` will pop that off and try to return to whatever address it finds, usually causing a crash.

Comment: @syacer Please check the edit I made to my answer. fuz would normally be right, but not actually in your case as I explain

Comment: @JohnBurger Thanks for the detailed answer. I totally agree with the two approaches and learned a lot. But I still have one a doubt: Isn't the purpose of "movq %rbp, %rsp" to be pop off the stack elements? I am confused that why this approach is a bad practice? Thanks! or maybe provide a case that this approach could cause problems

Comment: @syacer The “move `rsp` to ‘rbp`” at the beginning, and “move `rbp` to `rsp`” at the end of a function is only done there, not in the middle. `bp` stands for “base pointer”: the base of the current stack frame. Your function only calls one other function: imagine if it called a few? The stack should be cleaned after each function call, since the middle code might push intermediate values on the stack; nothing to do with calling functions. Best practice is to undo the stack operations after each function call.

Comment: @JohnBurger I understand the reason now. thanks for the explanation. One more question, when I use ret 4*8 in _myfunc, the compiler reports the following error: Error: operand size mismatch for `ret'. What is the reason for that?

Comment: @syacer: It's an immediate operand, so need a `$` prefix.  Try `ret $4*8`.

Comment: Apologies, yes. I use a different assembler, so I am unused to this syntax

Comment: my bad. I should notice this... $imm

Comment: I too made a mistake. I've been programming Intel assembly language for 40 years, and am always using the "destination is listed first" model. Your code is of course "destination is listed last", and I misinterpreted the arguments to `printf()`. They're supplied in registers from the stack, not vice versa